# Why do we need colon within double braces in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any difference between the following expressions?

```
<span ng-if="::ctrl.showUsername>{{::ctrl.asker.name || 'A stackoverflow participant'}}</span>
vs
<span ng-if="::ctrl.showUsername>{{ctrl.asker.name || 'A stackoverflow participant'}}</span>
```

Has it the same meaning as  (i.e. evaluate only once)

Comment: The `::ctrl.asker.name` just indicates one time binding, beyond that no.

Comment: In the first example, you are designating one-time binding on both the ng-if and the interpolated value (ctrl.asker.name). In the second example, the interpolated value will still be reevaluated upon every digest, but the ng-if will not.

Comment: You don't need it, what :: states is that the value does not need to be watched for changes so it is more performant for values that don't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the following expressions?

Yes, if you want to change the `ctrl.asker.name`.

> Has it the same meaning (i.e. evaluate only once)

No, `ctrl.asker.name` will be evaluated with every digest cycle, `::ctrl.asker.name` will stop evaluation after first digest once it becomes defined.

More from [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) or [here](https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/)